What does LO label mean for wiring?
We have a new light to put up on a wall. One of about 6. It is the only one that is a sensor light. The same brand and same light just sensor is different. Inside it has a wire block. L - LO - N. What is LO?  It’s the earth on the other lights but different labeling on this light.
Never seen this before. Also says it doesn’t need an earth. Just for info.

Probably "Live: Output". This is a live wire that is switched with the lamp. This way you can have multiple lamps turn on/off using a single sensor lamp.

That would make sense. Not earth then. Good to know. That would e why it said no Earth wire required. Thanks. :-)
